# How is possible build apk in terminal with different SIGN credentials

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, apk

I have build.gradle that can have `signingConfigs`, but I want TO ignore this setting and use other credentials. I don't want to edit or replace values in build.gradle.

Does gradle have same command like `gradle assemble -storeFile='PATH' -storePassword='password' -keyAlias='alias' -keyPassword='password'`?

If it's no way create signed apk with other `signingConfigs`, is it possible to create unsigned apk?

Answer (score 1):

**I suggest you using** the [solution reported by @Ranjan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56372184/2016562). It is the cleaner and a standard solution.

However if you would like to use the command line command, all properties passed to gradle in the command line via `-P` parameter are accessible in the `project` variable in your gradle script.
You can do something like that:

```
gradle assembleRelease -PmyKeyPassword='xxx' -PmyStorePassword='xxx' -PmyKeyAlias='xxx' -PmyStoreFile='...xxx.keystore'
```

and then define in your `build.gradle`.

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
      storeFile project.mystoreFile
      storePassword project.myStorePassword
      keyAlias project.myKeyAlias
      keyPassword project.myKeyPassword
   }
}
```

Pay attention because **it can cause errors** if you don't specify the keys in the gradle command (not so good in my point of view).
You can mitigate the issue doing a check on the parameter (using the `project.hasProperty(xxx)` method) and defining the **default** value in the `build.gradle`.

Something like that:

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
         storeFile project.hasProperty('myStoreFile') ? project.myStoreFile : 'default'
         //..
       }
}
```

Comment: @Gabriele, thanks to you now i know command line parameter options using 'gradlew'.  'gradlew --help'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no gradle build command which takes sign configs.
You have two options based on the requirement you mentioned in your question.

1.Edit the `build.gradle` to create multiple build flavors and provide different signing details for each build flavor.

```
    android {
    signingConfigs {
        abc {
            keyAlias 'abc'
            keyPassword 'yyy'
            storeFile file('keystore/astro.keystore')
            storePassword 'zzz'
        }
        xyz {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('keystore/sample.keystore')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
        //add another block for new customer
    }}
```

2. Create multiple copies of keystore properties file with different signing config and when you want to use one particular copy of keystore.properties file, rename it to "keystore.properties".

   `def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")`

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#secure-shared-keystore